# Michael Hartl Chapter 10: password/activate email link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-validation

I am going through Michael Hartl's tutorial and am stuck on the very end of Chapter 10. When I click "I forgot my password" - the email sends successfully. However the "Reset Password" link, directs me back to the home page, rather then the reset password page.

In views/password_resets/edit.html.rb

```
 <% provide(:title, 'Reset password') %>
  <h1>Reset password</h1>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>

       <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

       <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

       <%= f.label :password %>
       <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

       <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

       <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "noreply@example.com"

 def account_activation(user)
   @user = user
   mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
 end

 en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
    #
    def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
   mail to: user.email, subject: "Password reset"
  end
 end
```

views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb

```
<h1>Password reset</h1>

<p>To reset your password click the link below:</p>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
                                                  email: @user.email) %>

<p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>

<p>
If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

In models/users.rb

```
# Sets the password reset attributes.
def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
end

# Sends password reset email. 
def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
end

# Returns true if a password reset has expired.
def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'password_resets/new'

get 'password_resets/edit'

get 'sessions/new'

root              'static_pages#home'
get 'help'    =>  'static_pages#help'
get 'about'   =>  'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' =>  'static_pages#contact'
get 'signup'  =>  'users#new'
get 'login'   =>  'sessions#new'
post 'login'   =>  'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  =>  'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

end
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help.

Comment: Could you add your `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to figure this out, and finally discovered why I was having this problem. First of all, take a look at the routes file for this chapter Michael has on github here: [github](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/account-activation-password-reset/config/routes.rb)

My problem was simple. I hadn't authenticated the user for which I was trying to reset the password, thus I wasn't a valid user and couldn't reset my password.

Comment: I also ran into the issue where my user wasn't authenticated. Did you find that the user_mailer_preview user's reset_token returned false from BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
?
When I run this code, my reset_token doesn't match the user's reset_token that was actually generated by the password_reset_controller.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Hartl has his routes like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

I think your extra entries are short-circuiting the intended routes.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for the help. I will check later if this works. I am assuming it will!

Comment: I had adjusted the routes file to what you had suggested, three 'get' lines at the top.  Now when I click the "Reset Password" link, it loads for several minutes and then directs me back to the home page. Any help is appreciated. thanks,